# Does the file write() function append a carriage return?

Tags: python, python-2.7, file-io, carriage-return

In Python, do I need to append a '\n' to the string I'm writing so that the next string I write is not on the same line as the previous one?

Example code:

```
homeFilePath = "/home/myname/testFile.out"
fp = open(homeFilePath, 'w+')
fp.write("Line one")
fp.write("Line two")
fp.write("Line 3")
```

I'm looking for my file to contain:

```
Line one
Line two
Line 3
```

I should mention I'm using python version 2.7.5.

Comment: if you are free to choose your python version you **really** should switch to python 3.

Comment: No, the  file `write()` function does not (in Python 2 or 3).

Answer (score 2):

You can use `print` instead of `fp.write` directly.

```
from __future__ import print_function


homeFilePath = "/home/myname/testFile.out"
with open(homeFilePath, 'w+') as fp:
    print("Line one", file=fp)
    print("Line two", file=fp)
    print("Line 3", file=fp)
```

(This is far preferable to using the equivalent `print` statement, `print >>fp, "Line one"`, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

No, you do need to add a newline. Your code will give you output

```
Line oneLine twoLine 3
```

You could write your own function that appends it for you, like:

```
def writeNewline(fpIn, strIn):
    if (not fpIn.closed):
        fpIn.write(strIn + "\n")
```

You should then get the output you want using `writeNewline`:

```
fp = open(homeFilePath, 'w+')
writeNewline(fp, "Line one")
writeNewline(fp, "Line two")
writeNewline(fp, "Line 3")
fp.close()
```

Comment: true but in all fairness is it necessary to create a function that already exists